# Simple Go vs Java performance comparison in one particular application

Tags: java, performance, go

I create simple test which compare my Go and Java application performance
I do not know why but it looks like my Java application is faster than Go
I used:

```
~> go version
go version go1.15.6 darwin/amd64
```

and

```
~> java -version
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Go function mostly tested is:

```
func split(text string, occurrence map[string]int, separators []string) {
    words := strings.Split(text, separators[0])
    for _, w := range words {
        if len(w) > 0 {
            if len(separators) > 1 {
                split(w, occurrence, separators[1:])
            } else {
                occurrence[w] = occurrence[w] + 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java equivalent:

```
  private void split(String text, Map<String, Integer> occurrence, String[] separators) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text, separators[0]);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
      if (separators.length > 1) {
        split(st.nextToken(), occurrence, Arrays.copyOfRange(separators, 1, separators.length));
      } else {
        occurrence.compute(st.nextToken(),(k,v) -> v == null ? 1 : v+1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Start 10 threads and execute this method against text loaded from `ulyss10.txt` file in the loop (text is loaded into memory once on the beginning of application execution - it is not I/O test).

There you can see all files from test: https://github.com/TOlchawa/go-vs-java/tree/main/book_read_test

My expectation was Go will be faster - but results are opposite.
It looks like Go is little bit slower - about: 40% slower (which is unexpected)

[image]

I know this is not a very reliable test - but nevertheless I'm surprised.

**Could you provide me list of possible reasons why it was happen, please?**

in my understanding it is difference between:

- strings.Split | StringTokenizer
- slider | HashMap
- routine | Thread
- go compiler | JVM
- memory management | GC
- differences in source code of application (IMHO it is not an issue)

what else ?

//edit

There was a wrong version in Github repo - but during my tests I used correct and the question is still valid/open.

Comment: "My expectation was Go will be faster" honest question: why?

Comment: there is page with comparison Go and Java https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/go.html with opposite result

Comment: It's really hard comparing two different languages as you don't know if you have equivalent programs. I'm not really good with either Java or Go, but my first intuition is that Java's `StringTokenizer` might operate on the input string while `String.split` allocates and copy the input string. Another thing might be that their map data structure have different implementations, such as a HashMap, TreeMap or LinkedHashMap. Another reason might be that Go and Java has different debugging on by default. Java and Go also have different thread synchronization. There are too many factors.

Comment: agree - there many factors - just like in any other non-trivial application - still I am surprised

Comment: Are they creating the same amount of threads? In Java you create the threads explicitly, but in go you create coroutines (*goroutines*) and not threads. Maybe try to check the CPU usage, core usage and thread count for differences

Comment: Microbenchmark is an other word for lie. Especially if you compare different microbenchmarks.

Comment: this is not a question for 'microbenchmark' - I have 'something to do' - I created code which do the same in two languages and I am confused why Go implementation is slower than Java implementation - especially because my expectations was totally opposite. maybe I do mistake - and there is a question about - WHAT I DO WRONG?

Comment: CPU usage looks similar - in both cases CPU was consumed 100% - means: 1000%-850% (depends on other processes on Mac) - I executed it multiple times (more than on chart) - and not observed anything what can explain 40% difference in results

Comment: In the java version you run 100 threads, each doing 10 iterations. In the go version, you run 10 goroutines which each do 100 iterations, and which also start another 100 iterations in the background.

Comment: Paul Hankin, many thanks for find this bug! - fortunately it is not related to results - it was because I committed to repo wrong version - results are still correct - and question is still valid

Comment: Have you written a proper Go benchmark, and have you profiled the program through that benchmark? Making `split` recursive is definitely not the most efficient method, the jvm may just be able to optimize that out better. Scanning a string should be linear, not quadratic.

Comment: Yes, java is just better at optimizing the poor algorithm. Using a more reasonable algorithm will cut the execution time down by 90% and reduce memory allocation by many orders of magnitude.

Comment: @THM The benchmarksgame site output should be taken with a grain of salt: I have it on good authority that many contributions are not correct and the results are spurious. Do the tests yourself to make sure what you get is actually authentically true.

Comment: For me it seems there is a lot of resistance  to accepting the information thar Java may be faster than Go

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing a game of guessing. Here is what I would do to understand what happened.

1. Run a program profiling for both java and golang. Visualise them into memory allocation flow and flame graph.
2. See where each program spend most of their time.

Both golang and java has the same runtime speed for more/less equivalent low-level task that they do.

However, they underlying implementation for strings library can be different and hence lead to very huge performance difference.

For example, have you give a thought on how Golang vs Java implement a map? How about string splitting.

Any excessive bytes copy operations?

In real-world, performance optimisation are mostly cpu and memory management, not the "flashy" better big O algorithms. See Kafka vs RMQ. A lot of the performance edge came from better socket buffer management and zero-copy technique, which isn't rocket science algo at all.